# Best way to insert a property into an object in an array in an angular conroller

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a basic idea of what needs to happen, but I'm not sure of how to actually implement it. I have a GET call (**getTest**) in my controller which returns an array of objects. Currently in my view I'm running the array through the **ng-repeat** directive to show everything and using a whole list of **ng-if** directive calls to show certain icons depending on a value.

While this solution works, it feels a bit clunky. So what I'd like to do is have the controller itself look at the object property values in question for each object in the array and push a new property and value into the object with the name of the icon I want.

Here is my test controller:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('testApp').controller('TestController', TestController);

    function TestController(TestFactory, $state, $stateParams) {
        var vm = this;
        var searchID = $stateParams.id;
        vm.state = $state.current;
        vm.params = $stateParams;

        init();

        function init() {
            vm.testData = {};
            getTest();
        }

        function getTest() {
            TestFactory.getTestData(searchID).then(
                function(response) {
                    vm.testData = response;
                })
        }
    }

})();
```

If I were just dealing with 1 object I'd just have the **getTest** function go through the **response** object with an IF/ELSE and dump the results into a new variable, but how do I go about this with a whole array of objects? I'm assuming a FOREACH is needed to run through the array, but how would I insert the properties and values into the objects without destroying the other values in the objects?

Here is what the array basically looks like now:

```js
[
   {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
   },
   {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
   },
   {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
   }
]
```

Here is what I want it to look like when it's done:

```js
[
    {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2",
        key3: "value3",
        newKey: "newValue"
    },
    {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2",
        key3: "value3",
        newKey: "newValue"
    },
    {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2",
        key3: "value3",
        newKey: "newValue"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `angular.forEach`

```
angular.forEach(vm.testData, function(item,index){
  item.newKey = "newValue"
}
```

It will create new properties in each object in the array without destroying any of it.

Hope it helps.